# EvoPDF set document Language

Tags: evopdf

We are using EvoPdf 8.0 in dotnetcore 6 to generate PDF:s from HTML. We want machine readable info about the human language the page is written in.

In line with this page:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/pdf/PDF16
we want to add meta data about the human language used on th page.

I cannot find any property for setting this in EvoPdf when generating PDF.
Is this possible in EvoPdf? And if so, how?

Edit: And we are setting language in the markup, `<html lang="sv">`